# case when in.. where in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi stacoverflow community,

I have the following table.

```
  m_id s_s                    s_e                 a_s_t      comm  cosk
    101  2019-12-23 13:08:49  2019-12-23 13:13:12   NS        dt2   p2
    101  2019-12-23 13:13:12  2019-12-23 13:14:35   UP        dt2   p2
    101  2019-12-23 13:14:35  2019-12-23 13:14:56   MS        dt4   p4
```

I would like to set comm and cosk colums to null where a_s_t an is UP.

Can i do this using a case statement in my select statement?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case` expressions to *return* such data:

```
select (case when a_s_t <> 'UP' then comm end) as comm,
       (case when a_s_t <> 'UP' then cosk end) as cosk,
       ...  -- other columns
from t;
```

To actually change the data, you need to use `update`.

Comment: Thx for the comment. Will try it out

Answer (score 0):

To update the values, you can do something like this:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET comm = CASE WHEN a_s_t <> 'UP' THEN comm END,
    cosk = CASE WHEN a_s_t <> 'UP' THEN cosk END
```

You don't need to specify an `ELSE` condition, because it will default to `NULL`, which is what you want anyways.  Just change `mytable` to the actual name of your table.

Comment: thx for the comment. But i have a select statement where i create the above mentioned table result.